# Perl - how to convert a string that contains a space-separated words into a hash

Tags: perl

can someone help me how to convert a string that contains a space-separated words into a hash where the hash key is the word from the string and the hash value is the number of occurrences of the word from the hash?

thanks

Comment: Show your input and output example.

Comment: @mpapec: The problem description seems clear enough without an example, but it would be nice to see some attempt at a solution.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $string = "foo bar baz foo bar foo bar quux";
my %count;
$count{$_}++ for split /\s+/, $string;

print Dumper( \%count );
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'bar' => 3,
          'baz' => 1,
          'quux' => 1,
          'foo' => 3
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $string = "do re me fa so la te do";

  for $word ( split " +", $string )
     {
     $word_count{$word}++;
     }

  for $word ( keys %word_count )
     {
     print "$word\t$word_count{$word}\n";
     }
```

I prefer " +" to "\s+" because the later will cut on all white space.  You specifically said spaces so I wanted to cut only on actual spaces.

Comment: Not my favorite, but is the standard at my workplace (from Whitesmiths) so it's habit now.